# What is a decent way to say an approximate time?

Tags: word-choice

> I will arrive at 5 pm.

I don't know the exactly time I will arrive. So, I could say

> I will arrive **roughtly** at 5 pm.
>
> I will arrive **almost** at 5 pm.

That is my assumption. What is a good saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **around**

> I will arrive at around 5 pm.

Answer (score 1):

You could tell them you'd arrive

> five **-ish**

which is described [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiveish) as *Any time close to five o'clock.*

Comment: It's a fancy answer :)